# How to configure and use an early-access JDK in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to try JDK21 Early Access release but I don't see a compliance level of 21 or even 20 which is GA already.

In the latest official Eclipse distro highest level is 17.
In the latest Spring IDE the highest level is 18

How do I go about trying new features of JDK21 Early Access release from an IDE?

PS: I am going to need the new language features, so its not simply old java code running on a new VM.

[image]

Comment: Eclipse 2023-03 supports up to Java 19. There is a patch to support Java 20. I don't think the code for Java 21 is available yet. Look at the https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.27-P-builds/ update site for the patch

Comment: [Java 21 will be released in September](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/21/). Most JEPs targeting Java 21 are proposed but not yet confirmed. All new Java 21 language features that will no longer preview features in Java 21 (JEP 440 and JEP 441), are included in Java 20 as preview features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the same as previous releases, I would expect Java 21 BETA to appear on the Eclipse marketplace in September 2023.

Java 20 Support for Eclipse 2023-03 (4.27)
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-20-support-eclipse-2023-03-427

Java 21 Support for Eclipse 2023-09 (4.29) <del>Unreleased</del>
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-21-support-eclipse-2023-09-429

Java 21 implementation progress
https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues?q=milestone%3ABETA_JAVA21

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JDK-21 in Eclipse. By default Eclipse doesn't have JDK-21 yet still you can configure externally JDK21 in following ways:

Step(1): Download and install JDK-21 in any drive. I use Adopt JDK-21, https://adoptium.net/temurin/archive/

Step(2): Download Eclipse 2023-09 which is already available. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Step(3): Open your Java project in Eclipse and configure for new JDK-21

Step(3.1): Right click on project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries (tab) >  Select Existing JRE and click on Edit button > Click on Installed JRE button > Add > Standard VM > Next > Directory > locate home folder on JDK-21 (e.g. jdk-21+35) > Finish > Select JDK-21 from the list and Apply.

[image]

You are ready to use JDK-21 in Eclipse now. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Note: [Eclipse 4.30 RC2 (2023-12)](https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.30/jdt.php) does include:

> ### Java Language Features
>
> The release notably includes the following Java features:
>
> - [JEP 440: Record Patterns](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/440).
> - [JEP 441: Pattern Matching for Switch](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/441).